# How to fix clearInterval() not stopping the interval?

Tags: javascript, html, intervals

I made an interval connected to a button that only runs when you have a certain amount of money and lemonade. Then I created an if statement that makes it so that when you run out of lemonade, then the interval stops. I used clearInterval() and for some reason the interval doesn't stop, and the number of lemonade goes into the negatives. Obviously you can't have a negative amount of something!

I've looked at all of the other questions with similar problems to me, but they didn't really answer my question. They all have different variables and it was hard to find an answer pertaining to my code.

Here's my code:

```js
let autoBtnTwo = document.getElementById("autoBtnTwo");
let lemonade = 0;
let btnTwo = document.getElementById("btnTwo")

function btnTwoCost() {
  wallet.removeCash(20);
  update();
  document.getElementById("lemonade").innerHTML = lemonade += 30
}

function double() {
  if (wallet.getCash() >= 50) {
    wallet.addCash(2)
    update();

    document.getElementById("lemonade").innerHTML = lemonade -= 1;
  }
}

function autoLemonade() {
  if (wallet.getCash() >= 3000) {
    wallet.removeCash(3000);
    var myint = setInterval(double, 1000);
    autoBtnTwo.disabled = false;
    update();
  }
  if (wallet.getCash() <= 2999) {
    autoBtnTwo.disabled = true;
  }
  if (lemonade <= 0) {
    autoBtnTwo.disabled = true;
    btnTwo.disabled = true;
  }
}

function stopInterval() {
  var myint = setInterval(double, 1000);
  if (lemonade <= 0) {
    clearInterval(myint);
    stopInterval();
  }
}

function thousand() {
  wallet.addCash(1000)
  update();
  if (wallet.getCash() >= 3000) {
    autoBtnTwo.disabled = false;
  }
}

function Wallet() {
  return {
    addCash: function(val) {
      number += val;
    },
    getCash: function() {
      return number;
    },
    removeCash: function(val) {
      number -= val;
    }
  }
}

var number = 0;
const wallet = new Wallet();

var SUFFIXES = 'KMBTqQsSOND';

function update() {
  document.getElementById('number').textContent = getSuffixedNumber(wallet.getCash());
}

function getSuffixedNumber(num) {
  var power = Math.floor(Math.log10(num));
  var index = Math.floor(power / 3)
  num = num / Math.pow(10, (index * 3)); // first 3 digits of the number
  return num.toFixed(1) + (SUFFIXES[index - 1] || ''); // default to no suffix if it gets an out of bounds index
}
```

```html
<button onclick="autoLemonade()" class="chocolate-bar-auto" id="autoBtnTwo" disabled>
  Hire worker: <br> -$3000<br> Sells Lemonade
</button>

<button onclick="thousand()">to get to $3000 for testing </button>
<button onclick="btnTwoCost()"> buy lemonade -$20</button>
<button onclick="double()">sell lemonade </button>
<div class="cash-div">
  Cash: <div id="number">0</div>
</div>

<div class="lemonade-div">
  Lemonade: <div id="lemonade">0</div>
</div>
```

Sorry if this version is glitchy. All of the code I used to prevent the glitches makes the code longer, which it is already long enough. press the $3,000 button 4 times, then the buy lemonade, and then the hire worker button and you will see what happens once it gets to 0.

The interval should stop adding money, and stop reducing the amount of lemonade when lemonade reaches 0, but instead it keeps going into the negatives.

Comment: Move myInt OUTSIDE the functions

Comment: is that really it?  EDIT: i'm afraid that makes the interval automatically run, which is not what i want, nor does it stop at 0

Comment: Also use SPANS here `Cash: <div id="number">0</div>`

Comment: Why is stopInterval starting and stopping? Also it is never called

Comment: are you saying that is what it is doing? or are you asking if my problem is that it is starting and stopping?

Comment: It is hard to tell since you never seem to call it

Comment: Where is the function call of stopInterval() ?

Comment: I would expect the autoLemonade to be the one run in an interval and stopped when `lemonade <= 0`

Comment: your saying i should use autoLemonade in my setinterval?

Comment: setInterval and then clearInterval in the same method??? Does not make sense

Comment: @ThomasTallman review your last edit. First yo never call stopInterval() and inside this method you call the own function again?

Comment: Yes that is what I would imagine from what I can see without debugging your code

Comment: Currently you are creating two different timers, and are only stopping one of them. Apply the following fixes: move `var myint;` out of the function scope. Before calling `myint = setInterval(double,1000);` always clear the timer so that you have only one timer running at a time.

Comment: Also you might want to stop the interval if the user clicks another button to take over the sale

Comment: ill try that adder

Comment: nothing seemed to work, the interval keeps running even after i did everything you told me to do.